# Type safe objectdatasources

Tags: c#, asp.net, refactoring, objectdatasource

Is there any way to make asp.net objectdatasources to be type safe. Meaning I get a compile time error if parameters or datatypes change during refactoring?

Does anyone know any other method? Or can recommend any other way to do it? I find manual binding tedious. What is other people doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all binding is with strings holding property/column names.

Maybe consider a Test project (Unit testing). That would be my answer to the last part.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that. Yes Tests are a solution, but again I want to avoid having to do that, it would probably be the same effort as to do manual binding. I was just wondering what other techniques of data binding can help me here...