# Checking TypeName of ObjectDataSource at Compile time

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

Suppose I have page with an ObjectDataSource (ODS for short) inside, which provides bindings for a GridView.
As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774951/type-safe-objectdatasources), ODS does all bindings with Strings, so if I change the name of a class, which is referenced by TypeName property of an ODS, I won't get any compile time errors, only runtime ones.

Does anyone has any idea how to overcome this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

build up an ObjectDataSource in code instead of in your aspx....

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases using "AutoGenerateColumns" <strike>fixes</strike> avoids that problem.

However, I'm aware that's probably an incomplete answer to the actual question. I'm curious to see what solutions others offer. I'd hope or suspect a solution where you'd decorate properties of classes with attributes explaining how those properties should be bound in a grid.

*Edit: "avoids" seemed more appropriate than "fixes" :)*